# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Conve'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a tweak to an app and doing an UPDATE. It throws me the following error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Conve'.

My **DropDownList** loads the data perfectly but when I select any of that list to use its value and change it to the value that is in my **BD** it throws that error

Model: TableAsign.cs

```
public class TableAsign
{
    public long IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Controller: MastController.cs

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Asign_Conv(int idUsuario)
{
    List<Models.TableAsign> lst = null;
    using (TPConveniosEntities db = new TPConveniosEntities())
    {
        lst = (from d in db.Cliente
               orderby d.nombre
               select new TableAsign
               {
                   IdCliente = d.idCliente,
                   nombre = d.nombre
               }).ToList();
    }
    List<SelectListItem> items = lst.ConvertAll(d =>
    {   return new SelectListItem()
        {   Text = d.nombre.ToString(),
            Value = d.IdCliente.ToString(),
            Selected = false
        };
    });

    ViewBag.items = items;

    using (TPConveniosEntities db = new TPConveniosEntities())
    {
        Usuario user = db.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.idUsuario == idUsuario);
        return View(user);
    }
 }
```

In this part it performs the **UPDATE** and it seems to me that it has to do when I bring the value of my **DropDownList** with my **long** variable, it throws me the error and then when I consult my DB I see that if it performs the **UPDATE** but giving me that error

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Asign_Conv(FormCollection collection)
{
    using (TPConveniosEntities contexto = new TPConveniosEntities())
    {
        var idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(collection["IdUsuario"].Trim());
        Usuario user = contexto.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.idUsuario == idUsuario);

        var userName = collection["usuario"].Trim();
        long IdCliente = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Convenio"].Trim());

        user.userName = userName;
        user.idCliente = IdCliente;

        contexto.SaveChanges();
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

VIEW: Asign_Conv.cshtml

```
@using TPConvenios.App_Data;
@model Usuario
@{
    Layout = null;
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpciones = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "cuerpoPopUpGenerico2",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess_Asign",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure"
    };
    List<SelectListItem> items = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.items;
}
<div id="contenedor" style="margin: 15px 30px">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Asign_Conv", "Mast", null, ajaxOpciones, new { id = "Asign_Conv" }))
    {  @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
     <input type="hidden" name="idUsuario" id="idUsuario" value="@(null != Model ? Model.idUsuario : 0)" />
     <p>
       <input name="usuario" type="text" id="usuario" class="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" value="@(null != Model ? Model.userName : String.Empty)"/>
     </p>
     <p>
       @Html.DropDownList("Convenio", items, "Seleccione el Convenio", new { @class = "form-control" })
     </p>
     <p id="bot">
     <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Asignar" class="botonNuevo" style="float: right" />
     </p>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by bringing me the code with which I load my **DropdownList**, and pasting it to the POST where it performs **UPDATE**.

staying this way

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Asign_Conv(FormCollection collection)
   {
        using (TPConveniosEntities contexto = new TPConveniosEntities())
        {
            var idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(collection["IdUsuario"].Trim());
            Usuario user = contexto.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.idUsuario == idUsuario);

            var userName = collection["usuario"].Trim();
            long IDCliente = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Conve"].Trim());
           
            /*********** ESTO FUE LO QUE COPIE PARA QUE FUNCIONARA **********/
            
                List<Models.TableAsign> lst = null;
                using (TPConveniosEntities db = new TPConveniosEntities())
                {
                    lst = (from d in db.Cliente
                           orderby d.nombre
                           select new TableAsign
                           {
                               IdCliente = d.idCliente,
                               nombre = d.nombre
                           }).ToList();
                }
                List<SelectListItem> items = lst.ConvertAll(d =>
                {
                    return new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = d.nombre.ToString(),
                        Value = d.IdCliente.ToString(),
                        Selected = false
                    };
                });
                ViewBag.items = items;

               /***************************   HASTA AQUI   **********************/
                user.userName = userName;
                user.idCliente = IDCliente;
                contexto.SaveChanges();
 
                return View(user);
            }
        }
```